# specify time zone in cronR macosx

Tags: r, cron

I have a simple script to run a model at a set time everyday using `cronR`. Does anyone know how to specify the time zone in which the cron job is implemented.

Here is my simple script

```
# create the command to execute the R script
exec_model <- cron_rscript(rscript = path_model, cmd = file.path('/usr/local/bin/Rscript'),  log_append = FALSE)

# add the command and specify the days/times to start
cron_add(command = exec_model, frequency = 'daily', at = '04:31', 
         id = 'model', description = 'execute model')
```

the `cron_add` function allows me to specify the time - e.g. 04:31 - I assume this time is the time my system's clock? I would like to specify this to be 04:31 UTC and independent of my local time.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation of `?cron_add`, there is a `env` argument

> cron_add(
> command,
> frequency = "daily",
> at,
> days_of_month,
> days_of_week,
> months,
> id,
> tags = "",
> description = "",
> dry_run = FALSE,
> user = "",
> ask = TRUE,
> env = character()
> )

which can take the `Sys.getenv()`

> env - Named character; set environment variables for a cron job. Specify ‘Sys.getenv()‘
> to inherit the variables from the current R session

Therefore, we may change the `TZ` with

```
Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")
```

and specify the `env` as a named vector (after extracting the `TZ` with `Sys.getenv("TZ")`) to run the cron job

```
cron_add(command = exec_model, frequency = 'daily', at = '04:31', 
         id = 'model', description = 'execute model', 
   env = c(TZ = Sys.getenv("TZ"))
```